# Как подключить плагин babel?

Tags: webpack, babel

Имею такой конфиг webpack:

https://pastebin.com/dcGeA75L

Как мне к babel подключить вот это: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg ?

Comment: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-load-svg-with-react-and-webpack

Comment: Очень содержательно! А на примере имеющегося конфига?
P.S за второй линк - спасибо.

Comment: Не за что рад помочь.